# sfdx package versioning error for BillingCountryCode and MailingCountryCode field

Tags: community, salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I have one class where contact MailingCountryCode and account BillingCountryCode is used. I have added both objects in project but still I am getting error while versioning the package.
Error message>>

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
>   No such column 'BillingCountryCode' on entity 'Account'

Need help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that your [scratch org definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#!) both

- uses the correct configuration for a scratch org that includes the features required by your code:

  ```
  "features": ["StateAndCountryPicklist"],
  ```
- and is properly specified at the time of [package version creation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_pkg_ver.htm):

  ```
  sfdx force:package:version:create --package "MyApp" --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --wait 10
  ```

If you don't specify the configuration file for version creation, your deployment to the version scratch org will fail.