# Variable does not exist: MailingCountryCode

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org-definition-file, country-and-state

When I try to deploy to a scratch org a class that references the field **MailingCountryCode** on the object **Contact**, I receive the following error message :

```
Variable does not exist: MailingCountryCode (79:110)
```

In the dev org, I have **Standard Countries and Territories for Address Picklists** enabled so I guess that's why I'm not seeing this issue there, but from the documentation found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm), I understand that the field **MailingCountryCode** should be available even if that feature is not enabled :

> The ISO country code for the address. For example, this field is known as MailingCountryCode on Contact. CountryCode is always available on compound address fields, whether or not state and country/territory picklists are enabled in your organization.

If that's not the case, how can I set this feature as a dependency and how do I enable it from SFDX cli ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possibly this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291557/sfdx-package-versioning-error-for-billingcountrycode-and-mailingcountrycode-fiel

Comment: I guess this answers my second question, thank you. What about the doc that says the field should be available, am I mistaken in my understanding ?

Comment: doc is misleading, the xxxCode fields apply to StateAndCountryPicklists

Comment: In the past I've had to use dynamic SOQL for these code fields.